# How to completely initialise a component but not add it to the display? Flex

Tags: apache-flex, initialization

I need to completely initialize a custom component in my Flex app (i.e. I should be able to access it from action script and get its properties and its children etc), But I do not want to add it to the display or make it visible.

I have tried to add it to my visible component, but keep it visible, but often many of its properties are set only when it is drawn, so i don't get what i need.

Is there a way to add a custom component to some sort of 'Virtual' display, that is not visible to the user?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why adding it to the display list and keeping it invisible is not an option?

Comment: I think you are specifying the singleton class, creating the object there will not be visible to any one, until it is added as a child for any class. hence you can access anywhere in the application.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: The component I want to hide, is a third party component that we are using in our application. We do not have the source code for it.

Comment: @dev If you can otherwise instantiate and manipulate it, why can't you set it to `visible=false` ?

Comment: @weltraumpirat because it has some kind of lazy initialization inside, which does not happen till it is set Visible. And if you set it invisible after setting it visible, it destroys some of the inner components which will be reinitialize when it is set visible again.

Comment: @dev And what if you added it to an invisible Sprite?

Comment: @weltraumpirat: can you please post your last comment as an answer? It was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the component to an invisible Sprite - that way the component itself could both be on the stage and have its own `visible` property set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using initialize()? After a view is added to the display list, the initialization stage begins. Calling initialize() before addChild() should let you initialize the view without needing to first add it to the stage.

For more info visit:

- http://flexscript.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/flex-component-lifecycle-and-flex-component-framework/
- http://blog.deadinkvinyl.com/2008/10/05/flex-3-addchild-and-initialize/

Comment: That won't work (I've tried before). There are other methods that get called during component initialization. I gave up after half an hour of digging.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if possible without adding it to the display list, although I'd wish it were to some extent.

I once had to make custom drag proxy, which didn't work with the real component, because of some weird skinning issues. So instead I had `PopupMananger` add a box as a popup, added my component to the box, called `validateNow` on the component, drew it in a bitmap data, removed the popup, and used the bitmap data as the proxy.

So what you were trying was missing a call to `validateNow` most likely.